# (GitBlit) Why is my new remote repository not showing in the repositories tab but is available in my dashboard?

Tags: git, gitblit

I am new to GitBlit I have created a new repository inside gitblit. 
I made my commit in my local repository and successfully pushed my local repo to the remote GitBlit server.
When I login to my GitBlit acount I can see my repository inside my dashboard under the "Owned" tab on the right menu.
But when I click the Repositories Tab on the top Menu my new repository is not visible in the Repository list.  Why is this so, I beleive this behaviour is if the remote GitBlit repo is empty but I have successfully pushed to the GitBlit Server.  What did I miss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I beleive that is just how gitblit behaves by default.
It does not publicly display personal repositories ***~yourrepository/repo.git*** to the dashboard repository list.

You can change this inside the defaults.properties config file.
By default the value is set to false

```
web.includePersonalRepositories = false
```

[image]

Change it to true if you want personal repositories to be shown in the dashboard repo list.

```
web.includePersonalRepositories = true
```